# How to compare None Python and NULL SQLite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I scrape the site and write the result in the database, some elements may be `None`, this is not a problem, in the database they are displayed as `NULL`.
The problem is that before writing to the database, I check if this record already exists or not:

```py
cursor = await db.execute('SELECT * FROM MATCHES WHERE (a="{}" AND b="{}" AND c="{}".format(a, b, c)))
```

The problem is that `SELECT` thinks that `a = 'None'`but not `a = None`
And this is strange because when recording everything is ok:

```sql
INSERT INTO MATCHES (a, b, c) VALUES (?,?,?), (a, b, c)
```

In this case, if some element is `None` in the database then it will be `NULL`
I tried another option:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MATCHES WHERE (a=? AND b=? AND c=?), (a, b, c)
```

But it works like the first.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "NULL-safe"  operator `IS`:

```
SELECT * FROM MATCHES WHERE (a IS ? AND b IS ? AND c IS ?);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE tab(i INT, j INT);
INSERT INTO tab(i, j) VALUES (1,1),(NULL,NULL),(1,2);

SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE i = j;

SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE i IS j;
```

**[db-fiddle.com demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tk7JVhmq5Uwr72ua4astHM/0)**